# changing Certitificate "Intentend purpose"

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates, x509certificate2

Is it possible to change the certificate "Intended Purpose" for example if it has been ordered as "Client Authentication" to also include "Server Authentication" after the certificate was ordered or not? Most forums I looked at seem to indicate that the certificate has to be re-order. please note this certificate was ordered via a third party. Any feedback will be much appericated.

Answer (score 1):

> Most forums I looked at seem to indicate that the certificate has to be re-order

they are correct. The certificate is digitally signed by CA and any attempts to edit the certificate will invalidate the signature. You have to re-order the certificate from CA (third party, in your case).